# Vue 3.0 + Nuxt : still restriction "exactly one root element" in template (and :key bind)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

It was under my understanding that Vue 3 got rid of one-container restriction in template and the mandatory v-bind:key in v-for loops. But my code gives errors. i.e.:

"Component template should contain exactly one root element."

fyi I use vue-3 in combination with Nuxt... maybe that changes things.
Here is my package.json stack:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.24.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

The dependencies says I have Linting but this is not actively running..

**Anyone knows what is going on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt is only compatible with Vue2 as lf right now. Even if you use `@nuxtjs/composition-api`, this will not change the way the template is compiled (it is still Vue2 at the end of the loop).

The latter package only enables the use of composition API, this is not actually Vue3.